# Prove that $6x^5-55x^3 + 50x^2+15$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

We need to prove that $6x^5-55x^3 + 50x^2+15$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. We let $f(x) = 6x^5-55x^3 + 50x^2+15$. We use Eisenstein's criterion. We know that $(5)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. Then we have that $6 \notin (5)$. And $-55,50,15$ are all in $(5)$. And also $6 \notin (5)^2$.
Then according to Eisenstein's criterion, this means that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. I'm wondering if my proof is correct, because I think that it's too short. 
And if my proof is incorrect, could anyone point out the correct direction for me? Thanks!

Comment: $\frac{1}{5} \cdot 5=1 \in (5)=\mathbb{Q}[i]$. $(5)$ isn't prime neither in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as $(2+i)(2-i)=5$

Comment: @Marco I see. But then how should I prove that this polynomial is irreducible then?

Comment: If mu calculation are not wrong you can use Eisenstein's criterion with $(2+i)$, that is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and Gauss lemma

Comment: You need to chose a *prime* factor of $5$ and then you can apply Eisenstein - as in the linked dupe

Comment: The `dupe' is not asking the same question as this one. The two questions show different problems with applying Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @Joshua **Incorrect** - the dupe applies Eisenstein (+ Gauss's Lemma) in exactly the same way it applies here (the same way it applies in any UFD). We don't need a new Q&A for every possible polynomial that Eisenstein applies to, cf. [abstract dupes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using Eisenstein's criterion was right. Let's start by showing that the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]$.

First we need to show that the polynomial is primitive (i.e. it has no constant divisors). To do this we can consider the factorization of the coefficients. As shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) Gaussian primes are completely characterized so we have
$$
6=3 (1+i)(i-i)
$$
$$
-55=- 5 \cdot 11=-(2+i)(2-i)11
$$
$$
50=(2+i)^2(2-i)^2(1+i)(i-i)
$$
$$
15=3(2+i)(2-i)
$$
so $\gcd(6,-55,50,15)=1$. Now it is immediate to see that $(2+i) \mid 15,50,-55$ and $(2+i) \nmid 6$ and $(2+i)^2 \nmid 15$ so by  the Eisenstein's criterion the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i][x]$, so by Gauss lemma it is irreducible in $F[x]$, $F$ being the field of fraction of $Z[i]$, but such field is isomorphic to $Q[i]$, so the polynomial is irreducible in $Q[i][x]$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I've done an Approach0 search and the question doesn't show up.

Comment: There are hundreds of prior posts on how to use Eisenstein's criterion (on which this is a rote application assuming one is familiar with Gaussian integer arithmetic, as one should be if such a question is posed). There is nothing novel here.